# How to write Custom JAXB Adapter for a set of lists of a Datatype

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I've an object reference that needs to be parsed through JAXB and I need to write a custom adapter for this. The reference is

```
Set<List<CustomClass>>
```

I'm not able to understand how to write this out. Can someone help me with this?

The class files that I've are

a) Class File 1

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.mypackage.JobServiceDiscountsPOJO;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyDiscounts{

    private Set<List<JobServiceDiscountsPOJO>> jobServiceDiscountSet;

    //constructors

}
```

b) class File 2

```
   import java.util.*;

   @XmlRootElement
   @XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)    
   public class JobServiceDiscountsPOJO{
       int discountAmount=0; 
       //constructors and other methods
   }
```

I need to return class 1 i.e MyDiscounts through a Jersey-API service.

class File 3

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

        @Path("/discount")
        public class DiscountService{

        @POST
        @Produces("application/xml")  
        @Path("/couponCartValid")
             public String getDiscountsXML(){
                MyDiscounts discount=new MyDiscounts();
                try{
                   Marshaller jaxbMarshaller =jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                            StringWriter writerxmlObj = new StringWriter();
                            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(order, writerxmlObj);
                            String xml = String.valueOf(writerxmlObj);
                            xml = xml.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
                            return xml;
                }catch(Exception e){
                  return e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }
```

Comment: Please share some code and maybe an example data - otherwise you will hardly get good/relevant answers.

Comment: Some details such as HttpService parameters have been omitted as they aren't important for the discussion.

Comment: What is the XML you expect to get from `Set<List<JobServiceDiscountsPOJO>>`? And this is a very strange data structure, with Set making this unordered - so what would be the semantics with the Lists contained - in any order - within this Set?

Comment: Imagine a real world situation where I had to group some discounts together into combos. Here I would've to have a linked list of discounts which represents one combo. Then, there would be a group of discounts which are grouped into a Set. Essentially I would've a set of discounts and these discounts would be in combos.